# Почему не работает setState в промисе?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```js
<form className="offerForm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id='exampleForm'>
            <div className="offerForm__content">
              <div className="offerForm__data offerForm__item">
                <h2 className='offerForm__title'>Данные объявление</h2>
                <div className="offerForm__itemContent">
                  <h3 className='offerForm__text'>Заголовок</h3>
                  <input type="text" className='offerForm__input' onChange={(e) => setTitle(e.target.value)} />
                  <p className='offerForm__text'>Описание</p>
                  <textarea className='offerForm__descriptionInput' onChange={(e) => setDescription(e.target.value)} />
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="offerForm__img offerForm__item">
                <h2 className='offerForm__title'>Фото</h2>
                <div className="offerForm__itemContent offerForm__images">
                  <label className='offerForm__labelFile offerForm__imgItem' for="uploadImg">Добавить<br />Фото</label>
                  <input type="file" name="slider" onChange={(e) => setImages(e.target.files)} class="offerForm__inputFile" id="uploadImg" accept="image/*" multiple />
                  {[...images].map((file, i) => (
                    <img src={URL.createObjectURL(file)} className='offerForm__imgItem' width='150' height='150'></img>
                  ))}
                  {/* <Button onClick={(ev) => submitAxios(ev)}>Загрузить фото</Button> */}
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="offerForm__content">
              <div className="offerForm__info offerForm__item">
                <h2 className='offerForm__title'>Добавить новое объявление</h2>
                <div className="offerForm__itemContent">
                  <MyDropdown arr={optionsSection} placeholder='Раздел' onChange={(e) => setSection(e.target.innerText)}/>
                  {/* <Dropdown clearable search options={optionsSection} selection placeholder='Раздел' onChange={(e) => setSection(e.target.innerText)} /> */}
                  <Dropdown clearable placeholder='Подраздел' search selection options={subsection} onChange={(e) => setSelectedSubsection(e.target.innerText)} />
                  <Dropdown clearable placeholder='Тип' search selection options={typeAdConfig} onChange={(e) => setType(e.target.innerText)} />
                  {/* <Dropdown clearable className='ad__input' placeholder='Область' search selection options={uniqueSubject} onChange={(e) => setSelectedRegion(e.target.innerText)}/> */}
                  <Dropdown clearable placeholder='Город' search selection options={cityArr} onChange={(e) => setCity(e.target.innerText)} />
                  <Input placeholder='Цена $' onChange={(e) => setProductPrice(e.target.value)} />
                </div>
              </div>

              <div className="offerForm__contacts offerForm__item">
                <h2 className='offerForm__title '>Контакты</h2>
                <div className="offerForm__itemContent offerForm__contactsContent">
                  <div className='offerForm__contactsContainer'>
                    <p className='offerForm__text'>Имя</p>
                    <input type="text" className='offerForm__input offerForm__contactInput' placeholder='Добавить имя' onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)} />
                  </div>
                  <div className='offerForm__contactsContainer'>
                    <p className='offerForm__text'>Телефон</p>
                    <input type="text" className='offerForm__input offerForm__contactInput' placeholder='Укажите телефон' onChange={(e) => setPhone(e.target.value)} />
                  </div>
                  <div className='offerForm__contactsContainer'>
                    <p className='offerForm__text'>Эл.почта</p>
                    <input type="text" className='offerForm__input offerForm__contactInput' placeholder='Укажите почту' onChange={(e) => setMail(e.target.value)} />
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className='offerForm__content'>
              <div className="offerForm__btns">
                <h3>Объязательно для эффективности</h3>
                <div className='offerForm__btnContainer'>
                  <button type='button' style={status === 'gold' ? { backgroundColor: '#ece218' } : { backgroundColor: '#ecff18' }} className='offerForm__btn--gold offerForm__btn' onClick={(ev) => onChangeGold(ev)}>
                    Выделить золотым
              </button>
                </div>
                <div className='offerForm__btnContainer'>
                  <button style={status === 'silver' ? { backgroundColor: '#bec6c1' } : { backgroundColor: '#ddedd6' }} className='offerForm__btn--silver offerForm__btn' onClick={(ev) => onChangeSilver(ev)}>
                    Выделить серебряным
              </button>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="offerForm__btns">
                <h3>Увеличение продаж</h3>
                <div className="offerForm__btnContainer"><button style={serviceArr.includes('shares') ? { backgroundColor: '#78849A' } : { backgroundColor: '#B4C6E7' }} className='offerForm__btn--blue offerForm__btn' onClick={(ev) => onChangeService(ev, 'shares')}>Акции</button></div>
                <div className="offerForm__btnContainer"><button style={serviceArr.includes('sales') ? { backgroundColor: '#78849A' } : { backgroundColor: '#B4C6E7' }} className='offerForm__btn--blue offerForm__btn' onClick={(ev) => onChangeService(ev, 'sales')}>Скидки</button></div>
              </div>
              <div className="offerForm__btns">
                <h3>Больше заинтересованых соискателей</h3>
                <button className='offerForm__btn--gray offerForm__btn' style={serviceArr.includes('hots') ? { backgroundColor: '#808080' } : { backgroundColor: '#D9D9D9' }} onClick={(ev) => onChangeService(ev, 'hots')}>Горячие</button>
                <button className='offerForm__btn--gray offerForm__btn' style={serviceArr.includes('recommend') ? { backgroundColor: '#808080' } : { backgroundColor: '#D9D9D9' }} onClick={(ev) => onChangeService(ev, 'recommend')}>Рекомендованые</button>
              </div>
              <div className="offerForm__btns">
                <h3>Привлекающие внимание</h3>
                <button className='offerForm__btn--green offerForm__btn' style={serviceArr.includes('runStroke') ? { backgroundColor: '#8B9D7E' } : { backgroundColor: '#C6E0B4' }} onClick={(ev) => onChangeService(ev, 'runStroke')}>Бегущая строка</button>
                <button className='offerForm__btn--green offerForm__btn' style={serviceArr.includes('banner') ? { backgroundColor: '#8B9D7E' } : { backgroundColor: '#C6E0B4' }} onClick={(ev) => onChangeService(ev, 'banner')}>Баннер</button>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div>
              <h2>Price:{price}руб.</h2>
              <Button inverted color='brown' onClick={(ev) => onSubmit(ev,result)}>
                Подтвердить
              </Button>
            </div>
            <Liqpay price={price} />
          </form>
```

```js
async function wrap(ev, cb) {
    const btn = ev.target;

    ev.preventDefault();
    btn.setAttribute('disabled', true);

    const formData = getFormData();
    let json;
    try {
      json = await cb(formData);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }

    btn.removeAttribute('disabled');
    return json //добавил
  }


  function getFormData() {
    const formEl = document.getElementById('exampleForm');
    const formData = new FormData(formEl);

    for (const key of formData.keys()) {
      const val = formData.get(key);
      if (val === undefined || val === null || (typeof val === 'string' && !/\S/.test(val))) {
        formData.delete(key);
      }
    }

    return formData;
  }
```

Функция сохранения фото

```js
async function submitAxios(ev) {

    return wrap(ev, async (formData) => {
      const { data } = await axios.post(
        `${config.serverUrl}/api/images`,
        formData,
        {
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
            'Accept': 'application/json'
          }
        }
      ).then(res => setImgNames(res.data))

      return data;
    });
  }
```

Обновляю стейт result для дальнейшей отправки на сервер

```js
useEffect(() => {
    setResult({
      img: imgNames,
      section: section,
      subsection: selectedSubsection,
      type: type,
      // region: selectedRegion,
      city: city,
      productPrice: productPrice,
      priceAd: price,
      title: title,
      description: description,
      name: name,
      phone: phone,
      mail: mail,
      status: status,
      services: serviceArr,
    })
    console.log(result)
  }, [section, selectedSubsection, type, selectedRegion, city, price, title, description, name, phone, mail, status, serviceArr, productPrice, imgNames, images])
```

стейт компонента

```js
  const [section, setSection] = useState('Аудио,Видео,ТВ,Фото')
  const [stateSection, setStateSection] = useState(() => JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(category.default)))
  const [cityDataArr, setCityDataArr] = useState(() => JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(cityData.default)))
  const [uniqueSubject, setUniqueSubject] = useState()
  const [selectedRegion, setSelectedRegion] = useState('')
  const [subsection, setSubsection] = useState([])
  const [cityArr, setCityArr] = useState([])
  const [selectedSubsection, setSelectedSubsection] = useState('')
  const [type, setType] = useState('')
  const [city, setCity] = useState('')
  const [productPrice, setProductPrice] = useState('')
  const [price, setPrice] = useState(0)
  const [title, setTitle] = useState('')
  const [description, setDescription] = useState('')
  const [name, setName] = useState('')
  const [phone, setPhone] = useState('')
  const [mail, setMail] = useState('')
  const [status, setStatus] = useState('common')
  const [result, setResult] = useState({})
  const [serviceArr, setServiceArr] = useState([])
  const [images, setImages] = useState([])
  const [imgNames, setImgNames] = useState([])
  const history = useHistory();
```

Button

```js
<Button inverted color='brown' onClick={(ev) => onSubmit(ev,result)}>
  Подтвердить
</Button>
```

```js
const onSubmit = useCallback(async (ev,result) => {
    ev.preventDefault()
    const resultImg = await submitAxios(ev).then(res => setImgNames(res)); // в чем проблема. не записывает ответ в стейт, но console.log(res.data) рабоатет
    
    const adId = await axios.post(`${config.serverUrl}/api/offer`, result)
    .then(res => res.data._id)

    const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userData')).userId
    const userAds = await Promise.resolve(axios.get(`${config.serverUrl}/api/users/${user}`))

    const adsArr = [...userAds.data.ads, adId]
    const saveInUser = await axios.put(`${config.serverUrl}/api/users/newOffer/${user}`, adsArr).then(res => history.push('/home'))

  }, [result])
```

Comment: почему ты думаешь, что setState не работает?

Comment: А что возвращает `wrap`?

Comment: @Grundy Потому что в useEffect(setResult), не записывается img

Comment: Таки `wrap` ничего не возвращает.

Comment: @AlexeyTen Возвращает массив имен файлов которые записались на диск

Comment: @IhorStoner, покажи `return` внутри `async function wrap(ev, cb) {`

Comment: @Grundy, я добавил функции submitAxios  `.then(res => setImgNames(res.data)` .Но все равно ничего не получилось

Comment: @IhorStoner, ты не про то отвечаешь. внутри `submitAxios` ты делаешь `return wrap(...)` то есть возвращаешь результат выполнения функции `wrap`. А вопрос был, показать **внутри функции `wrap`** где ты используешь `return` и что-то из нее возвращаешь.

Comment: @Grundy добавил теперь возвращает json. Но мне и так и так приходил ответ с массивом имен. Почему то не срабатывает именно setImgNames(res). Но в консоль выводит все верно. Может это какой-то конфликт хуков и промисов. Хотя скорее всего проблема в кнопке onSubmit. Потому что если я добавляю submitAxios на другую кнопку и вызываю её срабатывание, то все нормально

Comment: Решил проблему, всем спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Почему-то не записывался результат в хуке useEffect при нажатии на кнопку отправки данных.
Я решил просто обойти проблему и записал результат в переменную, потом добавил результат выполнения функции картинок и все заработало. Но в чем конкретно проблема была я так и не понял

```js
const onSubmit = useCallback(async (ev) => {
    ev.preventDefault()
    const resultImg = await submitAxios(ev);
    let finnalyData = result;
    finnalyData.img = resultImg

    const adId = await axios.post(`${config.serverUrl}/api/offer`, finnalyData)
      .then(res => res.data._id)

    const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userData')).userId
    const userAds = await Promise.resolve(axios.get(`${config.serverUrl}/api/users/${user}`))

    const adsArr = [...userAds.data.ads, adId]
    const saveInUser = await axios.put(`${config.serverUrl}/api/users/newOffer/${user}`, adsArr).then(res => history.push('/home'))

  }, [result])
```